# Django Rest Framework Filters: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-filters

I'm using Django Rest Framework Filters (DRFF).
I have these two **models definition**:

```
class Release(models.Model):
    application = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='releases')
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    version_code = models.IntegerField()

class Application(models.Model):
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=144, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
```

and as you can see an Application has many Releases with releated_name='releases'.
So, I have these two **serializers**:

```
class ApplicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    releases = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = '__all__'

class ReleaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Release
        fields = '__all__'
```

these two **viewsets**:

```
class ApplicationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Application.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApplicationSerializer
    filter_class = ApplicationFilter

class ReleaseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Release.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReleaseSerializer
    filter_class = ReleaseFilter
```

and I have these two **filters (using DRFF)**:

```
class ReleaseFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Release
        fields = {
            'price': '__all__',
            'version_code': '__all__',
        }

class ApplicationFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    releases = filters.RelatedFilter(
        ReleaseFilter,
        queryset=Release.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = {
            'package_name': '__all__',
        }
```

My REST API is running on localhost:9000/api/v1/
but, when I try to see the Application view (in the browser: "GET /api/v1/application/") I get
this error: **"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'"**.

This is the **Traceback** for this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/application/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jfsanchez/Projects/kiosko/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jfsanchez/Projects/kiosko/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/jfsanchez/Projects/kiosko/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/jfsanchez/Projects/kiosko/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/jfsanchez/Projects/kiosko/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/home/jfsanchez/Projects/kiosko/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 706, in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/home/jfsanchez/Projects/kiosko/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 683, in get_context
    'filter_form': self.get_filter_form(data, view, request),
  File "/home/jfsanchez/Projects/kiosko/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 618, in get_filter_form
    html = backend().to_html(request, queryset, view)
  File "/home/jfsanchez/Projects/kiosko/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 61, in to_html
    filter_instance = filter_class(request.query_params, queryset=queryset, request=request)
  File "/home/jfsanchez/Projects/kiosko/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 186, in __init__
    self.filters = copy.deepcopy(self.base_filters)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 320, in _reconstruct
    value = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 306, in _reconstruct
    y.__dict__.update(state)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
[09/Nov/2017 14:49:29] "GET /api/v1/application/ HTTP/1.1" 500 664601
```

**And this is my (mainly) virtualenv stack:**

```
Django==1.11.4
django-filters==0.2.1
djangorestframework==3.6.4
djangorestframework-filters==0.10.2
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?
What's the problem here? What do I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: did you get any solution? I get this with  line 569, in render
    json_api_meta.update(self.extract_root_meta(serializer, serializer_data))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'